# is there a function that will add apostrophe to items inside an array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to apostrophe to items in an array. and return that into another array
I know I can use `foreach` to display it but I need the items to be back inside an array.

from: `array('blue','red','yellow');`

to: `array("'blue'","'red'","'yellow'");`

please help

Comment: Use array_map with a custom callback. And you can do this with a loop and put it back in an array. It's basic PHP actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

Use this PHP function :

```
$array=array('blue','red','yellow');

foreach ($array as $key=>$item)
{
$new_array[$key]="'".$item."'";
}

print_r ($new_array);
```

With array_map :

```
function myfunc($n)
{
    return("'".$n."'");
}

$a = array('blue','red','yellow');
$b = array_map("myfunc", $a);
print_r($b);
```

Comment: Your function adds double quotes, not single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly cleaner way:

```
function addQuotes($a) 
{
    return "'".$a."'";
}

$array = array('blue','red','yellow');

$array = array_map('addQuotes', $array);
```

A simple search would have landed you this very basic information though.  Please give effort next time.